# Removing individuals from cohort study data based on baseline characteristics

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have health data from a cohort study with repeated measures, where individuals are seen for multiple yearly follow-up visits. At baseline (visit 0), some individuals are already diagnosed with the disease of interest, while others aren't. As I'm looking at incident cases in my analysis, I need to remove those individual diagnosed as "sick" at visit 0 from my data. How might I do this in the tidyverse? I'm including an example below of the sort of data structure I'll be looking at:

```
subject_id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
visit <- c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
diagnosis <- c("not sick", "not sick", "not sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "not sick", "not sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "not sick", "not sick", "not sick", "sick")

cohort <- data.frame(subject_id, visit, diagnosis)
cohort
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This wouldn't work here, however, as this only removes the row for visit 0, not all rows for subjects who are "sick" at visit 0.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: If you want to drop them completely, then:

```
cohort %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>% 
  mutate(Condn = ifelse(visit==0 & diagnosis=="sick",1,0) ) %>% 
  filter(all(Condn==0))
```

**ORIGINAL**

We can do:

```
cohort %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>% 
   mutate(Condn = ifelse(visit==0 & diagnosis=="sick",1,0) ) %>% 
   filter(Condn==0) %>% 
   ungroup()  %>% 
   select(-Condn)
```

Comment: When I run this code, I receive the error message: ```"Error in filter(., Condn == 0) : object 'Condn' not found" ```

Comment: Use `dplyr::filter`. Not sure why that happens. Could you show me the full code you used?

Comment: ```subject_id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
visit <- c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3)
diagnosis <- c("not sick", "not sick", "not sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "not sick", "not sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "sick", "not sick", "not sick", "not sick", "sick")

cohort <- data.frame(subject_id, visit, diagnosis)

cohort %>% 
  group_by(subject_id) %>% 
  mutate(Condn = ifelse(visit==0 & diagnosis=="sick",1,0) ) %>% 
  filter(Condn==0) %>% 
  ungroup()  %>% 
  select(-Condn)```

Comment: Use `dplyr::filter` and let me know.

Comment: It does run with ```dplyr::filter() ``` but it only selects out visit 0 row for the participants of interest, not all of their rows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you update your question? **As I'm looking at incident cases in my analysis, I need to remove those individual diagnosed as "sick" at visit 0 from my data.**

Comment: yes the code now works with the edit that you made. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
cohort %>%
 group_by(subject_id) %>%
 filter(first(diagnosis) != "sick")

   subject_id visit diagnosis
        <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    
 1          1     0 not sick 
 2          1     1 not sick 
 3          1     2 not sick 
 4          1     3 sick     
 5          3     0 not sick 
 6          3     1 not sick 
 7          3     2 sick     
 8          3     3 sick     
 9          5     0 not sick 
10          5     1 not sick 
11          5     2 not sick 
12          5     3 sick
```

Or:

```
cohort %>%
 group_by(subject_id) %>%
 filter(diagnosis[row_number() == 1] != "sick")
```

Comment: The first option seems to convert the df to a time series when I run it: ```Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 20 
Frequency = 1 
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
 1    1    0    1
 2    1    1    1
 3    1    2    1
 4    1    3    2
 5    2    0    2
 6    2    1    2
 7    2    2    2
 8    2    3    2
 9    3    0    1
10    3    1    1
11    3    2    2
12    3    3    2
13    4    0    2
14    4    1    2
15    4    2    2
16    4    3    2
17    5    0    1
18    5    1    1
19    5    2    1
20    5    3    2
> ```

Comment: When I run the second option I receive this error: ```Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace ```

Comment: You're using the wrong `filter` I think. Use `dplyr::filter`. @West_End_Line

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Looks like ```filter() ``` was being masked by base R filter. I ran it with ```dplyr::filter ``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for their advice. @tmfmnk and @NelsonGon both provided options that worked for this task.

I recently moved from SAS to R, and this was extremely helpful.